# What is the difference between 'silhouette' and 'silhouette'(cluster) of 'Silhouette Plot' in Orange3?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, orange, silhouette

Orange3

1. After clustering data with the 'K-means' widget, the 'Silhouette Plot' widget was connected. After that, I connected the Silhouette Plot to the Data Table widget. At this point, the data table contains columns 'Silhouette', 'Silhouette (Cluster)'. At this time, what is the meaning of the values of the 'silhouette' and 'silouette (cluster)' columns?
2. Is the individual bar graph in the Silhouette Plot widget 'Silhouette coefficient'? And what is the value of 'Cluster'?
3. The Silhouette Plot widget document explained the Silhouette Score. Is it correct?

The created silhouette plot shows the silhouette score for each instance in the data.

https://orange3.readthedocs.io/projects/orange-visual-programming/en/latest/widgets/visualize/silhouetteplot.html

How to calculate the silhouette score of kmeans
The meaning of the Silhouette, Silhouette (cluster) column in Silhouette Plot,